# Python3.4 SSLV3 Handshake failure with asyncio, aiohttp

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, ssl, python-asyncio

I've got a problem with the following code, I get an SSLV3 handshake failure:

```
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import ssl

def main():
    conn = set_conn()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(get_thing('https://example.com', conn))

@asyncio.coroutine
def get_thing(url, conn):
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('get', url, connector=conn)
    print(response.text)

def set_conn():
    context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
    context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    context.check_hostname = True
    context.load_verify_locations('/path/to/cert.pem')
    conn = aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl_context=context)
    return conn

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/grahat03/workspace/ent/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 344, in _create_connection
    **kwargs))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 437, in create_connection
    sock, protocol_factory, ssl, server_hostname)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 453, in _create_connection_transport
    yield from waiter
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 348, in __iter__
    yield self  # This tells Task to wait for completion.
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 370, in _wakeup
    value = future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 243, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 605, in _on_handshake
    self._sock.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/ssl.py", line 805, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:598)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/grahat03/workspace/ent/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 164, in connect
    transport, proto = yield from self._create_connection(req)
  File "/Users/grahat03/workspace/ent/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 348, in _create_connection
    (req.host, req.port)) from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError: Can not connect to example.com:443

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 10, in main
    loop.run_until_complete(get_thing(urls[0], conn))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/base_events.py", line 208, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/futures.py", line 243, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/asyncio/tasks.py", line 317, in _step
    result = coro.throw(exc)
  File "stackoverflow.py", line 14, in get_thing
    response = yield from aiohttp.request('get', url, connector=conn)
  File "/Users/grahat03/workspace/ent/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 104, in request
    conn = yield from connector.connect(req)
  File "/Users/grahat03/workspace/ent/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 168, in connect
    raise ClientOSError() from exc
aiohttp.errors.ClientOSError
```

I'm on Mac OSX 10.9.5, Python version:

```
python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
3.4.1 (v3.4.1:c0e311e010fc, May 18 2014, 00:54:21)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]
```

OpenSSL seems to be ok, I can make the connections as follows:

```
openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 -cert /path/to/cert.pem
```

I suspect there is something I'm not doing correctly when creating the ssl context. Any ideas please?

Comment: Did you tried to fetch the same resource via `urllib` or `requests`?

Comment: I can retrieve the resource with `requests` no problem.

Comment: BTW, are you sure about `SSLV3`? In your example you do use `SSLV23` which is different protocol.

Comment: I wondered about that too, but the stack trace corresponds to the code I've used.

Comment: Hmm. Dunno. You may file a bug in https://github.com/KeepSafe/aiohttp/issues but I doubt if I can help you. I need a code example to reproduce your case, that's impossible with "example.com" and without real certificates. Self-signed pair and hand-made aiohttp.web server may be ok though.

Comment: have you tried to [reproduce the issue using only `context.wrap_socket()`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/104624/1321) without `asyncio` and/or `aiohttp`?

Comment: I won't file a bug yet, since I suspect there is something wrong with my system and I cannot supply my certificates. I have since solved my original problem using different code, but I may try and reproduce the issue (eliminating components) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to use a different SSLContext method:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
context.load_cert_chain('/path/to/cert.pem')
```

And this had nothing to do with aiohttp.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed aiohttp can have this error even when requests and curl don't. You can use curl to find an ssl context that works.

```
> curl -v <url> > /dev/null
...
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
} [318 bytes data]
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
...
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / AES256-GCM-SHA384
```

Experiment to see what is actually needed. In my case, it was only the cipher.

```
import ssl
import aiohttp

# use one of:
#ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context()
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH, cafile="/etc/ssl/cert.pem")

# optional
ssl_context.options = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
ssl_context.set_ciphers("AES256-GCM-SHA384")

# create session or pass to each request with `ssl=ssl_context`
async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=aiohttp.TCPConnector(ssl=ssl_context)) as s:
    ...
```